# JBOSS Clustering setup in 4 and 5 version

Tags: jboss

Could any one let me know what are all steps or required configuration we need to follow to create the cluster in Jboss server 4 and 5 ?

Thank you,
Amar Neeluri

Comment: I am stuck at this issue as well. Did you find a solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

Please check jboss documentation site for [cluster](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Clustering_Guide/4/html/index.html), gives detailed steps for every component.